# how do i set disabled button to false in jQuery, am using the bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, html, class

I am trying to set disabled button to false but seems it's not working. I am using Bootstrap 4 styling.

```
$(".quote").attr(".disabled", false);
```

I expect the button to be active but keeps telling me disabled is not a valid attribute.

Comment: Yes, that would be the expected outcome/error. Remove the dot before 'disabled'. That should then work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the .prop() function and remove the dot from .disabled like so...

```
$(".quote").prop("disabled", false);
```